# Запрос на 2 условия

Tags: база-данных, mysql, запрос, sql

Как составить запрос на такой выбор:

Выбрать запись с `id=5`, и если такой нет, то с `id=3`.

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (5,3);
```

возвращает и 5, и 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN(5,3) ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Чтоб указать определенный приоритет, надо хитрить. Как-то так:

    ...order by find_in_set(id, "5,3")...

Comment: `ORDER BY id` отсортирует записи по возрастанию: 333555555. Чтобы получить желаемое поведение сортируйте по убывающей.

Answer (score 2):

Если предпочитаемый ID всегда больше (или всегда меньше) непредпочитаемого, то можно сортировать по ID (order by) и выбирать только первую запись (limit).

Или забирать все данные и потом в приложении выбирать более предпочитаемые.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `id` = 5
UNION
SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `id` = 3 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM `tableName` WHERE `id` = 5);
```